# How to make new project wizard visible in File ->New->Example... in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I made a new wizard plug-in for eclipse. I can run this wizard by either `File->New->Project` or `File->New->Other`. However, I want to make it available via `File->New->Example...` as well. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the category id `org.eclipse.ui.Examples`

An example entry from the EMF examples:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
  <category
        id="org.eclipse.emf.examples.EMF"
        name="%_UI_EMFExampleCategory_name"
        parentCategory="org.eclipse.ui.Examples">
  </category>
  <wizard
        id="org.eclipse.emf.examples.ActivitiesWizard"
        name="%_UI_ActivitiesWizard_name"
        class="org.eclipse.emf.common.ui.wizard.ExampleInstallerWizard"
        category="org.eclipse.ui.Examples/org.eclipse.emf.examples.EMF"
        project="true"
        icon="icons/full/ctool16/NewEMFExample.gif">
     <description>%_UI_ActivitiesWizard_desc</description>
  </wizard>
```

Comment: It also occurred to me this morning to take a look at source code of one of the examples that came with my eclipse :) Thank you @greg-449